# What is the physics concept in sponge filter

Tags: fluid-dynamics, everyday-life, water, popular-science

**I really need help I want to ask what is the physics concept in Sponge Filter?**[image]

Comment: Is there any exact word for it?

Answer (score 1):

The sponge is there to distribute the suction over a large area so that fish don't get sucked into the pump and trapped or injured.  Without it, weak, sick, injured, or large-surface-area fish could get pinned by the suction at the water intake.

Comment: Sponges are also used to break up air bubbles from air pumps which increases the surface area of the bubbles and helps oxygen to dissolve in the water.

Comment: Is there any exact word for it?

Comment: @user36908 Diffusion?